# Performance Issue while using cursor expressions in SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, cursor

Facing performance issue while iterating  through the ResultSet of an  SQL query with cursor expressions.

```
SQL query(example)
select id, name , cursor (select id,name from subject  ) as cusr1 from student
```

This is how I am retrieving the cursor in java

```
statement = connection.createStatement(); 
         resultSet=statement.executeQuery(query);
          while (resultSet.next()) { //Read every row
                int columnCount = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) { //Read every column
                    String columnName = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(column);
                    Object value = resultSet.getObject(columnName);
                    if (value != null) {
                        System.out.println("Value Not Null");
                        if(value instanceof ResultSet){
                            System.out.println("Success");
                            ResultSet rs1=(ResultSet)value;
                            while(rs1.next()){
                                String name=rs1.getString("name");
                                System.out.println("Name is "+name);
                                Long id=rs1.getLong("id");
                                System.out.println("Id is "+id);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }         
            }
```

The execution time of the  query is very less compared to the processing time of the resultSet (iterating through the same ,getting the cusror data etc).

Am I doing anything wrong here?Is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: Did you mean to correlate the cursor with the outer query? At the moment you are just returning all subjects every time.

Comment: yes.The cursor would be correlated to the outer query